# how to grep information from trigger details in azure functions blob trigger (python)

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

how can I access the trigger details (**insertionTime**) shown in the monitor of an azure function inside the function call:

```
import azure.functions as func

def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    insertionTime = ???
    blob_created = myblob.blob_properties.get('Created')
    blob_modified = myblob.blob_properties.get('LastModified')
    size = myblob.blob_properties.get('ContentLength')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can see these Invocation details right after the function gets triggered by default.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer;
yes, for sure, but how can I access this information inside the callback function? e.g. if I want to save the "insertionTime" in a separate sql table
"size in bytes", "created" and "last_modified" I can get get

size = blob.blob_properties.get('ContentLength')
last_modified= blob.blob_properties.get('LastModified')
created = blob.blob_properties.get('Created ')

but the "insertionTime" I cannot find anywhere